# Cognos 11.2.2 - Adding a new currency to Cognos

Tags: cognos, cognos-11

could someone please point me to the right direction?

When formatting a column of a list or crosstab as a currency, I'd like to add The West African CFA franc (XOF). Right now it's not in the menu. How could I add it to the currency list?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

IBM provides documentated instructions for adding a custom currency symbol:  https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cognos-analytics/11.2.0?topic=settings-customizing-currency-support

At the time of this writing, there is an error in the instructions.  I have notified IBM Support.  The file you'll need to edit is install_location/configuration/i18n_res.xml

It looks like XOF/CFA is already in the list, although the currency symbol is shown as CFA and should probably be F.CFA.

Comment: Hello dougp, thank you. I dont see this currency in the list, will ask the administrator to add it via the file you mentioned.